# Validation in custom operation controller

Tags: rest, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to do a validation only on a custom operation on api platform but it doesn't work.

I would like to change the password only if there is no error in the validation but in any case the password is changed.

If I remove the validation groups from the validation annotations it works.

for example if i replace **@Assert\NotBlank(groups={"put-reset-password"})**  with  **@Assert\NotBlank** the validation pass.

This is the code of the entity :

```
  "CHANGE-PASSWORD"={
    "method"="PUT",
     "path"="/users/change-password/{id}",
     controller"="App\Controller\ChangePasswordController",
     "access_control"="is_granted('EDIT-PASSWORD', previous_object) and object == user",
     "openapi_context"={
        "summary"="Change Password"
     },
     "denormalization_context"={
        "groups"={"put-reset-password"}
     },
     "validation_groups"={"put-reset-password"},
  },
```

and here is my controller

```
public function __invoke(User $data)
{

    // Validate data and handle validation errors
    $this->validator->validate($data);

    $data->setPassword($this->userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getNewPassword()));


    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $token = $this->tokenManager->create($data);


    return $data;
}
```

and here is one of my attributes in which i use validation group.

```
/**
 * @Groups({"put-reset-password"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"put-reset-password"})
 * @UserPassword(groups={"put-reset-password"})
 */
private $oldPassword;
```

Any issue please ?

Comment: The validator's validate method return a constraints violation list. You have to check the count of violations to know if the data are valid.

Comment: @FlorianHermann In this case, the constraints violation list return nothing, it seems like when i put groups into assertion of an attribute, the validation fail. Even if i var_dump($this->validator->validate($data)) i have NULL.

Comment: That seems strange because the validate method is always supposed to return a ConstraintViolationListInterface instance even it the validation is ok.

Comment: I know but i think that validator doesn't like when im using validations_group inside assertion

Comment: You mentioned custom operation. Did you try something like this to apply your validation group on your custom operation? https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/#using-validation-groups-on-operations

Comment: of course and my custom operation here is **CHANGE-PASSWORD**

Answer (score 1):

This is strange behavior.
You get null probably because you use interface

`use ApiPlatform\Core\Validator\ValidatorInterface;`

If use inface `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface` you must be get object `ConstraintViolationListInterface`.

I have a similar problem. The following solution helped me:

```
/**
 * @Groups({"put-reset-password"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Default", "put-reset-password"})
 * @UserPassword(groups={"put-reset-password"})
 */
private $oldPassword;
```

It's strange, but after added `"Default"` my validation is worked in my custom operation.

Useful links:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I have the absolute same case not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same case and I had just kind of made things to work with the `Default` group, but the actual solution is to give the validator the group you want to validate:

```
public function __invoke(User $data)
{
    $this->validator->validate($data, null, 'put-reset-password');
    ...
}
```